# Put identifiers to objects inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I created this array:

```
var arr = [1, "ikanej", b={name:"Olsi", surname : "Angjellari"}]
```

Is there a way to refer to third element of this array with an identifier?

Like this

```
arr.b.name  // this doesn't work
```

and not like this

```
arr[2].name // this does but you need to keep track of index.
            // It would be easier to have an identifier
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an array? For the way you're using it, you don't need order, and can just use an object literal. That way, you could access the item like `obj.b.name`

Comment: I'm just studying javascript... No apparent reason!

Comment: Ahh I see. Well my next question would be - what all are you storing in this array (or hopefully object)? You seem to have a mixed structure above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you should use arrays to store collections of elements with something in common (a list of strings, a list of DOM elements, etc). Usually you wouldn't need to access them with "a name", so using the index would be fine.

```
var workers=[worker1, worker2...];
```

If you have a bunch of objects no directly related (for example, all of them are attributes of another object) you should group them in an map-like object.

```
var worker1= { name: "John Smith", age: 32, email: "js@myCompany.com" };
```

Your example seems to be a mixture of both, so you can "fake" an array using an object:

```
var fakeArr={};
fakeArr[0]=... //fakeArr.0 won't work, identifiers cannot start with digits
fakeArr[1]=...
fakeArr["b"]=... //fakeArr.b will work
```

But it seems quite impractical, I have never seen anything like that in any project I've been working

Comment: Ok, i see. The reason i asked this question is because i was looking at a tutorial and the lecturer said you can put even objects inside arrays, and reference them by index. I thought maybe there's a way to reference by identifier. Anyway, thanks for the answer. even an answer that you can't do certain thing or it's not practical or not "best practice", is a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an object instead array :

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/AV36f/1/

**JS**:

```
var arr = {0:1, 1:"ikanej", b:{name:"Olsi", surname : "Angjellari"}};

$('.body').append(arr.b.name);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I hear "everyone" is using arrays of objects. And the above is not an array of objects, it's just an object.

Comment: @Olsi: What do you mean by `I hear "everyone" is using arrays of objects`?

Comment: I'm new to javascript and i see tutorials on the web. They mention often arrays of objects. Maybe they are talking about json or something else.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing there, is defining an array. Each element can be of any type, but if you want to reference by name instead of index number, you will have to use objects as mentioned in other answers.

The reason why 
    `var arr = [1, "ikanej", b={name:"Olsi", surname : "Angjellari"}]`
is not raising a Syntax Error is because `b={name:"Olsi", surname : "Angjellari"}` is defining `b` as a global variable. Don't confuse with a way to define a index name for an array element.
So in fact `arr[2] === b`.

Since an array is just another object, you could modify it after creation:

```
var arr = [1, "ikanej", b={name:"Olsi", surname : "Angjellari"}];
arr['b'] = arr[2];

arr['b'] === arr[2] === b; //true
arr.b.name === 'Olsi';
```

The prior example just illustrates a concept and is not practical, so I still recommend using a plain object in your case:

```
var arr = { 
    0: 1, 
    1: "ikanej", 
    b: {name: "Olsi", surname: "Angjellari"}
};
```

Comment: Damn, I've been so much time writing my answer I did not realize this one was more or less the same exaplanation :P

Comment: That happens to me all the time!